# Looking for a list of values in a dict and retuning its key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have this dict:

```
d = { 'car'  : ["ford", "fiat", "vw"],
      'bike' : ["fant","xorg","niky"]}
```

And I am getting 3 string input from user:

```
a=str(input())
b=str(input())
c=str(input())
```

If the inputs are:

```
ford
fiat
vw
```

I should get `"car"` as output

I am trying something like this:

```
for a,b,c in d.values():
    print(d.keys())
```

but its not working, of course as it will print all d.keys no matter what the inputs are.
Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Sidenote: `str(input())` is redundant. `input()` already returns a `str`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a list comprehension:

```
print(next((k for k, v in d.items() if v == [a, b, c])))
```

Example output:

```
ford
fiat
vw
car
```

*Note: `input`s are always strings, so `str(...)` is not required, you could just use*:

```
a = input()
b = input()
c = input()
```

Comment: Thanks man.  Just one question:  How can I change the output from ´ ['car']  to car (without [ and ')?

Answer (score 0):

```
d = { 'car'  : ["ford", "fiat", "vw"],
      'bike' : ["fant","xorg","niky"]}
a=str(input())
for k, v in d.items():
    if a in v:
        print(k)
        break
```

Comment: moumou Thanks.  Prob with your answer is that sometimes a we can have one of the three values with more than 1 key.  I needed the the exactly 3 values to match a key as @U12-Forward did.   Thank you very much for your help tho xD